# Links for the DialogFlow extension go to Drupal 404 Page

Tags: drupal-8

I'm on Drupal 8.

Just installed DialogFlow, but when I go to DialogFlow>Settings I leave CiviCRM and get a Drupal 404 page- "Page not found".

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there - what is the URL that is giving you the 404?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed that sometimes in drupal 8 you have to clear *drupal* cache to get newly added civi menu links to be found.

Comment: This is the answer, we are tracking this in core with a view to fixing it.

Comment: @HomoTechsual - could you add the issue reference? I had a quick look but couldn't find it

Comment: @michaelmcandrew Looks like this one: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/37

Comment: thanks @Demerit!

Comment: actually mikey says it is this one: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/-/issues/105 :) (they are linked in any case)